# unable to access Some Controller in MVC 4 on IIS 7 application Deploying server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

i am using MVC4 with EntityFramework 4.4. 
i have published my application on IIS 7; and it's Publish successfully( means i can access my dashboard controller page by simply login controller), but i am unable to access other controllers/methods. show error...
***The resource cannot be found***. 
 I think may be my project folder structure are not in well format.

[Image of My Project Folder stracture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOiwA.png)

My route config File

```
namespace PVS_WEB
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "LoginIndexPVS", id = UrlParameter.Optional }               
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the `MVCPVS` in the URL? Is it a virtual-directory defined by IIS?

Comment: it my project name.. and yes it virtual directory name

Answer (score 0):

> The resource cannot be found.

It is simply means that the file it is looking for does not exists at location. Make sure you are using correct destination.

Comment: on localhost  its working perfectly... but not working on IIS

Answer (score 0):

Solved...

I just Recompiled  the project and host it again; and it solve.